# Alternative/substitute for queryCommandState('bold')

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I created a rich content editor based on `execCommand` and `queryCommandState` whose are now [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandState). I'm looking for a substitute to these commands, especially for

```
document.queryCommandState('bold')
```

I think the following is a good start:

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

I get the current selection, but I can't figure out if the selection is in bold `<b>` or not.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done with `window.getSelection()`

**JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/s54zoxk2/

**Explanations:** https://lucidar.me/en/rich-content-editor/lightweight-rich-content-editor-part-2-check-if-bold/

Hope this will help others...

Answer (score 1):

You could get all computed styles of the node and then check the value of your propertie.

```
function getComputedStyles(currentNode) {
    if(currentNode.id != maxTreeNodeId) {
        try {
            var styles = window.getComputedStyle(currentNode);
            console.log(styles.fontWeight); // Print font weight, 700 = bold
        } catch(err) {
            this.getComputedStyles(currentNode.parentNode);
        }
    }
}
```